# Ubuntu package names which ends with "lua"

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, lua

Searching through the Ubuntu package repositories (packages.ubuntu.com) i recently found packages which names ends with "lua" for example "Package: dnsmasq-base-lua" or "Package: weechat-lua". What are these packages?

Comment: Lua is a programming language: https://www.lua.org  Those packages has (optional) Lua intergations.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apt show dnsmasq-base{,-lua}` to see the differences between the package descriptions:

If I compare the `Description:` of `dnsmasq-base` to `dnsmasq-base-lua`, I see `-lua` provides:

> This package is an alternative to dnsmasq-base which includes the LUA interpreter.

When I compare the `Description:` of `weechat` to `weechat-lua`, I see `-lua` provides:

> This package provides the Lua scripting API plugin.

As @Kusalanda mentioned, Lua is a scripting language and these packages provide some Lua integration.